# Android Xamarin C#: app runs in emulator but in actual device gets error: [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_MANIFEST]

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

My app runs perfectly in the android emulator but when I try to deploy in debug configuration it fails and tells me this:

```
3>:Deployment failed
3>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
3>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_MANIFEST]
3>
3>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
3>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyD.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
3>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
3>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
3>Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
3>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_MANIFEST]
```

I can't seem to figure what this error really means, other than it is something to do with the android manifest?

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="scout.app" android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="0.0.0" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <application android:label="Scout" android:debuggable="true"></application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT:

So when I try to deploy sometimes this error pops up instead:

```
2>:Deployment failed
2>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
2>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK]
2>
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyD.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
2>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK]
```

EDIT 2:

Sometimes this error pops up instead as well even if I havent changed anything..

```
1>:Deployment failed
1>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES).
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass89_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
1>Deployment failed because of an internal error: The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES).
```

EDIT 3:

This is the manifest from App/obj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="scout.app" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.0" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <application android:label="Scout" android:debuggable="true" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="InstructionReciever" android:name="md5f8bfa05656068c3725933b788fa9610f.SmsReciever" />
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Scout" android:name="md5657830f1484ab57cd89db0f9549d303a.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="UsbListener" android:name="md5787c3ec38a313bacb6190da23f10b0af.UsbConnectReciever">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="UsbListener" android:name="md5787c3ec38a313bacb6190da23f10b0af.UsbDisconnectReciever">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="scout.app.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.scout.app" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is scout.app your full namespace?

Comment: Manifest looks ok to me and the static analyser in MFractor showed no issues. Maybe run it through an xml formatter to tidy it up, uninstall the app completely and try again?

Comment: @LibinJoseph Yes, that is the full name space.

Comment: @matthewrdev Tried and it didnt work, the app is not even installing, im running this through visual studio just hitting the play button to try run it on the phone but this error happens when it tries to deploy so yeah its not installing

Comment: @wootank Next step is to grab the manifest generated by the build chain. Navigate to `[ProjectName]/obj/[Debug/Release]/android/` and open `AndroidManifest.xml`. Please include the contents of that as well as the one you currently have in the question.

Comment: @wootank : Have you overriden any Activity class names?

Comment: @matthewrdev Cool, edited question to include it

Comment: @LibinJoseph I dont think so? How would I know if I did?

Comment: I've had similar _sorts_ of things when trying to debug after installing a release version.  Fix was to manually uninstall the app via the app manager on the device first.  Sometimes it shows up in the app manager under the namespace only rather than the application name.  Might be worth trying?

Comment: @wootank : you would mention that on top of the Activity class. If you did, you have to write a fully qualified name. Please check this documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Activity_Name

Comment: @GregHNZ Yes!!! That did it! thank you kindly, if you post it an answer i'd happily mark it accordingly :)

Comment: I have the same exception when I use Android Studio run my app into my phone. Then I use adb command to install the build app(the app-debug.apk in build-outputs-apk), same exception again. But finally I use gradle installDebug command, and it helps me to install app to my phone. I just don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar sorts of errors occur when trying to debug after installing a release version.

The fix was to manually uninstall the app via the app manager on the device first.

Sometimes it shows up in the app manager under the namespace only rather than the application name.