# Application Installation Failed with INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_MANIFEST error

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

Firstly, there seems to have a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36636286/6482350), but mine is some weird. I just new a simple project with some simple activities, but when I run it to my phones with the run button in Android Studio, I get the `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_MANIFEST` error in some specific phones(other phones don't have this error). And then I use adb command to install the build app(app->build->outputs->apk->app-debug.apk) to my phone, the error appears again in these specific phones. But when I finally use gradle command(installDebug), everything is ok.

The `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paiyipai.ocrdemo">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SheetDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AnalysisResultActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the specific phone is vivo Y67, which is made in china. I've searched for a long time on net, but it came to nothing. Please help or try to give some ideas about how to fix this.

Comment: vivo Y67 is Android OS, v6.0 (Marshmallow) while your  android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Comment: @Charuක I modify the `targetSdkVersion` to 23 and add runtime permissions, but it doesn't work. It is to say I can't run the app from Android Studio directly. Or I just delete the `uses-sdk` configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml and configure it in the build.gradle, can't work, either. :(